# What is a good book for a Lightroom newbie?

Tags: lightroom, books

I've been trying out Lightroom 3 for awhile, and like what I see. I will be buying it in the near future, thanks to a student discount. I'm sure I've only just scratched the surface so far, and being a visual learner, I could use suggestions for learning material.

I'm interested not just in the editing process, but also in the overall workflow - organization, tagging, metadata, and so on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd highly recommend Scott Kelby's [Adobe Photoshop Lightroom 3 Book for Digital Photographers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321700910)

Scott really knows his stuff and is a great author.

Comment: I'd second this, have the book for version 2 of lightroom and it's a great read and very useful.  Keep coming back to it!

Comment: agreed. this would be a good first book.

Comment: This does look like a good book to have handy. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

Also video based is the [Luminous Landscape](http://www.luminous-landscape.com/videos/lr3.shtml) tutorials. The price is $49.95 for the tutorial, which doesn't seem too bad, and there's no DRM, just download the full set and view as desired.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Martin Evening](http://www.martinevening.com)'s [The Adobe Photoshop Lightroom 3 Book: The Complete Guide for Photographers](http://www.peachpit.com/promotions/promotion.aspx?promo=136959).

I am currently reading it, and, as a Lightroom beginner, I find it informative, well written and with a very nice choice of photos (it is definitely not devoted to fashion only, which was something that I feared).

Comment: I haven't read that one but I found Martin Evening's Photoshop for Photographers books very well written. He's a great author.

Answer (score 0):

Instruction video rather than a book: [Photoshop Lightroom 3 Essential Training](http://www.lynda.com/home/DisplayCourse.aspx?lpk2=59972) by [Lynda.com](http://www.lynda.com/). The training videos from Lynda.com I've watched so far (including this one) are excellent. Drawback, esp. for students and others with limited budgets: neither subscription nor DVD (you choose either one) come cheap :-(

Answer (score 0):

Kevin Kubota's [Digital Photography Bootcamp](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1584281693) is relatively short but very useful and covers a Lightroom-based workflow.  It also some basic Photoshop recipes that I find very helpful.  It's slanted towards pros who shoot weddings, but you can see how to apply it to your own situation.